# Modularization of Backend (Django)

Tags: django, web, nginx, backend

I'm learning Django/backend programming but I'm not exactly sure how to organize all of my stuff. I'm planning on having two websites with different domains, one is a personal one, and another one is for an organization.

What would be the best way to create this with Django? Would I separate this into two projects, and have all of the files in each project? Should I create an app for each section of the site? Or should I put it all under one project, and have an app for each website?

Also, as a quick side question, why do I have to run Nginx and uwsgi instead of just using Django? I don't exactly understand the difference between all these things. NginX is a proxy server, that sends requests to uwsgi, which then goes to Django, right? It seems excessive. I don't even know where to start, in terms of creating a host name router..

Thanks a lot, and if you can any good reading links/books let me know!

Answer (score 0):

1. As a beginner you better stick with different projects for
   different domain, when you gain more experience, you will find out
   how much of the logic is reused in both and then make a decision of reusing the apps in single project.
2. Please read the section on wsgi: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/